# unsupported parameter in future method

Tags: apex, future

I am trying to create a future method and pass in the following parameter:

```
@future
private static void myMethod(Map<Id, List<String>> userMap) {
```

I get unsupported parameter type.

I can do:

```
@future
private static void myMethod(Map<Id, String> userMap) {
```

I know I can't pass objects, but why is a Map with a list of strings no longer accepted?

Is there a way I can do this using JSON serialize/deserialize?

Thanks.

Comment: You could serialize the map with a list, to a sting, pass the string to the future, then deserialize yes.

Comment: would it just be as simple as: `String JSONString = JSON.serialize(MyMapWithStringList);`

Comment: Possibly, yes. All depends on your requirements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Future method parameters are limited to primitives and collections of primitives. You're attempting to pass in a collection of collections, which is not supported.

You're correct that you can use JSON to get around this. This should put you on the right track:

```
// populate this however you were previously
Map<Id, List<String>> userMap = new Map<Id, List<String>>();

// serialize your data before calling the future method
myMethod(JSON.serialize(userMap));

@future
private static void myMethod(String userMapSerialized) {
    // deserialize back into our map of lists
    Map<Id, List<String>> userMap = (Map<Id, List<String>>)JSON.deserialize(userMapSerialized, Map<Id, List<String>>.class);

    // and away we go...

}
```

A more detailed example can be found here: [Passing Objects to Future Annotated Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/passing-objects-to-future-annotated-methods.html).

Also, please take a look at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4872/151) regarding the potential implications of using this technique.

Comment: This saved me so much heartburn. Genius.